# VHDL: can not have such operands in this context (sobel filter)

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
    --use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
    --use ieee.std_logic_signed.all;


    entity sobel is 
         port ( 
              top_left_pixel      : in  std_logic; 
              top_middle_pixel    : in  std_logic; 
              top_right_pixel     : in  std_logic; 
              middle_left_pixel   : in  std_logic; 
              middle_right_pixel  : in  std_logic; 
              bottom_left_pixel   : in  std_logic; 
              bottom_middle_pixel : in  std_logic; 
              bottom_right_pixel  : in  std_logic; 
              sobelx              : out std_logic; 
              sobely              : out std_logic 
         ); 
    end entity sobel; 

    architecture noddy of sobel is 
        signal p1 : std_logic := top_left_pixel;
        signal p2 : std_logic := top_middle_pixel;
        signal p3 : std_logic := top_right_pixel;
        signal p4 : std_logic := middle_left_pixel;
        signal p6 : std_logic := middle_right_pixel;
        signal p7 : std_logic := bottom_left_pixel;
        signal p8 : std_logic := bottom_middle_pixel;
        signal p9 : std_logic := bottom_right_pixel;

        signal sobelx_s : integer;
        signal sobely_s : integer; 

    begin 
        -- Same error on both these lines
         sobelx_s <= (p3 - p1) + ((p6 & '0') - (p4 & '0')) + (p9 - p7); 

         sobely_s <= (bottom_left_pixel - top_left_pixel) + ((bottom_middle_pixel & '0') - (top_middle_pixel & '0')) + (bottom_right_pixel - top_right_pixel); 

    end architecture noddy;
```

I am trying to build a sobel filter in VHDL with very little experience. This entity is made just for trying it out with a test bench to see if the sobel-algorith works on the input data.

Any suggestions?

All answers are really appreciated, and if you could direct a complete VHDL beginner to something useful, you're welcome

Comment: Are your input and output pixels really single bits?

Comment: No they are not, they are 8 bit values, thank you for the heads up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code [looks familiar](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/comp.arch.fpga/TqAJoQOOaww) :)  I thought `architecture noddy` was a bit unusual...

Try this (from the link above) instead:

```
entity sobel is

    port (
        top_left_pixel      : in  integer;
        top_middle_pixel    : in  integer;
        top_right_pixel     : in  integer;
        middle_left_pixel   : in  integer;
        middle_right_pixel  : in  integer;
        bottom_left_pixel   : in  integer;
        bottom_middle_pixel : in  integer;
        bottom_right_pixel  : in  integer;
        sobelx              : out integer;
        sobely              : out integer
    );

end entity sobel;
architecture noddy of sobel is

begin  -- architecture noddy

    sobelx <= (-1*top_left_pixel)+(-2*middle_left_pixel)+(-1*bottom_left_pixel)
              +(1*top_right_pixel)+(2*middle_right_pixel)+(1*bottom_right_pixel);
    sobely <= (-1*top_left_pixel)+(-2*top_middle_pixel)+(-1*top_right_pixel)
              +(1*bottom_left_pixel)+(2*bottom_middle_pixel)+(1*bottom_right_pixel);
end architecture noddy;
```

Comment: `integer` _will_ work, but beware this type is kind of "virtual" and doesn't represent any signal. When synthesizing an `integer`, its width will be set to the maximum number of bits used. To have a signal, you have to be able to feed a value using a finite number of wires so it has to fit on a number of **bits**. `std_logic_vector` can easily be casted to `signed`/`unsigned` (as long as they have the same width) and then maths can be done.

Comment: @eepp: There's nothing virtual about integers. Integer is perfectly able to be used as a signal and is synthesisable! And use signed/unsigned if that's what you mean, rather than casting slvs.  (BTW  I've even compared vectors vs int: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27921/when-is-it-neater-to-use-vector-representations-vs-integers .)  And you can even use integers as top-level ports (although it's a bit of a faff.)

Comment: I know, that's what I said: _When synthesizing an integer, its width will be set to the maximum number of bits used._. What I mean by _signal_ is not the `signal` keyword, but the `port` ones connecting to real-world wires. If you want `sobelx` to be directly connected to LEDs, I don't think an `integer` will work: you have to be able to address each bit of it so it must have a declated width. Of course you can connect entities using `integer`s, but at the end, if you intend to constrain your port signals to wires, `std_logic_vector` is usually expected.

Comment: @eepp: OK, I misunderstood, you mean top-level port.  You *can* use an integer (either constrained to define the width, or the default 32 bits) as a top-level port, as I say - it's a faff as the synthesiser will create a collection of internally-named pins for you to map.  But it does work.

Comment: Ok! I never tried, in fact, but I was told that in a course (damn courses). It's true an `integer` is 32-bit so I guess it's going to disconnect all unused pins. So one thing worth mentioning would be: you must use `unsigned`/`signed` for over-32-bits integers.

Comment: Well, after some help from you guys and fiddling with the filter, I now have a working one.
Pixels are 8 bit vectors and calculations are done with 
`Gx <= ("000" & p3-p1)+(("00" & p6 & '0')-("00" & p4 & '0')) + ("000" & p9-p7);` 
I do absolute value operation on both before adding them to G.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the Sobel operator is usually applied on a grayscale image using convolution. Or otherwise maybe you really want a binary image. So the Sobel matrix is something like:

```
-1 0 +1
-2 0 +2
-1 0 +1
```

for a horizontal change. You want to convolute this with your original image. Try having a grayscale input first and then maybe you can try with a binary image input.

The reason you are getting your VHDL errors is that you cannot *add* (`+`) or do any maths on `std_logic` or `std_logic_vector`. You need to use the `unsigned` and `signed` types (probably `signed` here) which overload the maths operators. Use the `numeric_std` library for that (your VHDL environment should have that; it's pretty standard).

If you have a real entity though, of which the inputs are real signals, they should be `std_logic_vector`. You then need to cast those to `signed`/`unsigned` by following [this graph](http://nova.polymtl.ca/~simark/types.html).